# Rails Paperclip Phonegap Heroku S3- How to return image files from an Ajax request through the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cordova, heroku, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am creating a mobile app through Phonegap as the client and using Rails as the back-end. I am deploying my app to Heroku and am planning to use S3 to store the image files, because that is what is recommended from my various readings online.

I was wondering how could the Rails controller be used to send images back from Ajax requests from Phonegap.

I am not sure how to write the back-end API code to send images to requests.

I also read that using the send_file method without x-send_file enabled will slow down the server because sending the image would block other request until it is done.

Please let me know if you have any insights.

Answer (score 0):

You could use redirects to the S3 assets here, then your browser is just getting the image directly, and not holding up one of your server processes while the browser slowly downloads the images.

If you need to keep your images private you can use the signed URL feature of S3 to only give signed and time limited URL's to the appropriate users.  (See my commit to Paperclip: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/pull/292)